# Possible to create a custom if binding in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to create an "fadeInIf" custom binding. My thoughts were something equal to the "fadeVisible" from: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html:

```
// Here's a custom Knockout binding that makes elements shown/hidden via jQuery's fadeIn()/fadeOut() methods
// Could be stored in a separate utility library
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        // Initially set the element to be instantly visible/hidden depending on the value
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).toggle(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)); // Use "unwrapObservable" so we can handle values that may or may not be observable
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        // Whenever the value subsequently changes, slowly fade the element in or out
        var value = valueAccessor();
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value) ? $(element).fadeIn() : $(element).fadeOut();
    }
};
```

I'm pretty new to custom bindings, but thinking it could be something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeInIf = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).toggle(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value));

        ko.bindingHandlers.if.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value))
            $(element).fadeIn();

        ko.bindingHandlers.if.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
};
```

I've got the "fadeVisible" working, but can't work this one out, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion. 
I finally got it working, I was missing the [controlsDescendantBindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html) option. Here's the result:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeIf = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).toggle(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value));

        ko.bindingHandlers['if'].init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: value };
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)) {
            ko.bindingHandlers['if'].update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
            $(element).fadeIn();
        }
        else {
            $(element).fadeOut(200, function () {
                ko.bindingHandlers['if'].update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it right at 99%, however the fade in would not be done after the first time...  I think it has to do with how the "if" binding handler works though. What I've done is to change this:

```
    if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value))
        $(element).fadeIn();
```

into this:

```
    if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)) {
        $(element).toggle(false);
        $(element).fadeIn();
    }
```

I've saved a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YqLGR/1/) of it working if you want to check.